# Unable to fetch tweets using tweepy for a particular user

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I'm new to tweepy. I collected all the followers of a particular user, and using their ids, I am trying to extract their last 100 tweets. My code is able to extract tweets for some users and not for other users. In one try it is able to extract the tweets for a particular user and in the next try it couldn't extract.

My Code :

```
def get_api(cfg):
  auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(cfg['consumer_key'], cfg['consumer_secret'])
  auth.set_access_token(cfg['access_token'], cfg['access_token_secret'])
  return tweepy.API(auth)

def getStatuses(api,id,statusLimit = 100 ):
  global TOTAL_REQUESTS
  statusFlag = True
  statusList = []
  page = 1
  screenName = None
  while statusFlag:
    for i in range(5):
      try:
          statuses = api.user_timeline(user_id = id,page = page,count=100)
          TOTAL_REQUESTS += 1
          break
      except:
          print " FAILED user " + str(id_user) + ", retrying"
      time.sleep(4)
    if len(statuses) > 0 and len(statusList) < statusLimit:
      tempList = [(status.id_str,str(status.retweet_count),str(status.favorite_count),status.created_at,str(status.place),str(status.source),status.text) for status in statuses]
      statusList.extend(tempList)
      if len(statusList) > statusLimit:
        statusFlag = False
      page+=1
    else:
      statusFlag = False
  print "Loaded user %d . total %s" % (id_user,len(statusList))
  return statusList

def getWordCounts(api,user,statusLimit):
  # Parse the user
  statuses = getStatuses(api,user,statusLimit)
  wc = {}

  #Loop over all the entries
  for e in statuses:
    text = e[6]
    print text
    #Extract a list of words
    words = getWords(text)
    for word in words:
      wc.setdefault(word,0)
      wc[word]+=1

  if len(statuses) > 0:
    return statuses[0][1], wc   
  else:
    return screen_name(api.lookup_users(user)), wc
def main():
  cfg = { 
    "consumer_key"        : "aaa",
    "consumer_secret"     : "bbb",
    "access_token"        : "ccc",
    "access_token_secret" : "ddd" 
    }

  api = get_api(cfg)
  #user = "bogas04"
  userids = []
  #have to append that user id in this
  for page in tweepy.Cursor(api.followers_ids,screen_name = "bogas04").pages():
      print page
      userids.extend(page)
  #userids.extend(api.me())

  output = open('usersData.pk1','wb')

  wordCounts = {}
  apCount = {}

  for u in userids:
    try:
      screeName,wc = getWordCounts(api,u,STATUSES_MAX)
      wordCounts[screeName] = wc
      print screeName + 'OK!'
      for word, count in wc.items():
        apCount.setdefault(word,0)
        if count > 1:
          apCount[word] += 1
    except:
      print 'Failed to parse the user %s' %u
  pickle.dump(wordCounts,output)
  pickle.dump(apCount,output)
  output.close()

main()
```

Any sort of help will be much appreciated. Please help!

Comment: Please do not include your API keys in your questions. I have removed them, but you should assume they are now compromised. Please revoke them immediately.

Comment: I'm sorry.I mistakenly forgot to remove them.Yes I've changed the keys.If you could hep me with the problem stated above, it would be much appreciated! :)

Comment: @PulkitAggarwal, what problem do you get? No errors? Also narrow down the code to where the problem is.